# Provide configuration file to Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, swift3, xcconfig, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to marry swiftpm and .xcconfig files.

I've created `Config.xcconfig` file right next to my `Package.swift` file with two lines:

```
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(SRCROOT)/../3rdparty/mylib/.build/
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -lmylibRelease
```

But I still have 120 linkage errors, my guess is that `swift build` does not see my config file.

What should I do?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Xcode 11.3 supports now SPM with custom Xcode configurations.

Comment: and how do you set up a custom Xcode configuration for the package that you import?

Comment: Flagged as not an answer. As is, this should be a comment.

Answer (score 9):

[SwiftPM support](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/55acae81c69c992b9517faee0f8464e3b63b8677/Sources/Commands/SwiftPackageTool.swift#L267) custom Xcode configs. You have to specify the path to your custom config file when invoking `generate-xcodeproj` command.
To see more details about `generate-xcodeproj` run `swift package generate-xcodeproj -h`

**Example**

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides Config.xcconfig
```

Comment: Ohh, so I cant use configs with `swift build`? Only XCode?

Comment: Yes thats right, and it makes sense. xcconfig is a Xcode config file and It can be used only by Xcode. If you need custom configs then you have to generate Xcode project and build it from there.

Comment: My problem was that I couldn't find a way to pass additional library search paths etc. I end up using a bunch of `-Xlinker` stuff, but that ruins the whole thing because now it can't be used as a SwiftPM package.

Comment: @s1ddok have you found a better solution? I also need to add some LDFLAGS to swift build ...

Comment: warning: Xcode can open and build Swift Packages directly. 'generate-xcodeproj' is no longer needed and will be deprecated soon. July ’21.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to specify a header search path, and linker flags, is to use the `Package.swift` struct values. They are provided for that very purpose.

For header search paths, use [CSetting](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html#csetting).

For linker flags, use [LinkerSetting](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html#linkersetting).

Full specification of Package.swift can be found at the [PackageDescription API](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/index.html).